# Garbage collection for a shared process

Tags: android, process, garbage-collection

I have a sticky Service that is using the same process with the Application.

But when I close the application and the super.onDestroy() is called for the MainActivity the process does not perform garbage collection.

The only way I found is to terminate the process and wait untill the Service comes back with the same clean process (7 mb instead of 52 mb).

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

This works fine. Is there a better way to clean up a process without terminating the process? (calling finish() and System.gc() does not work!) Thank you so much.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? You should use just `finish()` to close activities and `stopService()` to stop sticky services.

Comment: I need to garbage collect the activity and keep the service running. When I call finish() the process is still alive with garbage left from the activity (what is almost 45 mb). I haven't found a good way to do that... without restarting the process with only the service.

Comment: You didn’t answer @Héctor’s question. The question was “Why do you need to do that?” and your response was just “I need to…”, only repeating your claim *that* you need that, not even remotely explaining *why*.

Comment: I want to use only one process without creating an extra remote one for the service.